# onclick handler does not execute assigned function

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('image011').onclick = hideTopMenu();
​}

</script>
```

In my case, I cant use JQuery, I need to use pure javascript only.
Can someone tell me where the problem is?
After page load, if I click on image011, the top menu will be hidden. Regards

Comment: And what's the problem? What're you asking? Does it work, does it not work? Are you asking *how* to do this? Or why it's not working?

Comment: So the top menu will be hidden or will it not? What does the `hideTopMenu()`function?

Comment: Im working on an existing website with sharepoint  so this function already exist and i dont know the code but it hide the top menu     when i need to use it i should call it in this way : javascript:hideTopMenu();   here i have to hide the menu when i click on the image because a pop up will appear , so i need to hide it  but its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign a *function reference* as event handler.

What you are doing is, assign the result from the function call `hideTopMenu()`

So, your line needs to look like:

```
document.getElementById('image011').onclick = hideTopMenu;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your original post, the code makes your point clear :)

Comment: let me clarify more for u , Im working on an existing website with sharepoint so this function already exist and i dont know the code but it hide the top menu when i need to use it i should call it in this way : javascript:hideTopMenu(); here i have to hide the menu when i click on the image because a pop up will appear , so i need to hide it but its not working

Comment: @rolandfeghaly: its still pretty vague. What happens? Nothing? Error message? If the *function* **hideTopMenu** is within a resolvable parent context, it will assign the method as event event handler and it will get executed on click.

Comment: man , i did  only this         <script type="text/javascript">

     document.getElementById('image011').onclick = hideTopMenu ;

     </script>